# jquery rotate more than 1 element at a time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use [this script](https://github.com/trev/Rotatable) for making elements rotatable, which uses jQueryUI.

It binds to an element with

```
var elem = $('.elem-wrapper');
 elem.parent().rotatable({ //
   autoHide: false
 });
```

I then have multiple elements setup with the 'elem-wrapper' class, setup exactly as the singular example in the project. Works fine with one element, but not with multiple.

Is there a way to make this run on multiple elements?

**Edit**: Got to this stage in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanjaypoyzer/sSXLD/) but it rotates all elements with that class name at the same time. Any way to only do it so it's rotating the one I've selected?

Comment: i downloaded the plugin , and when i open the index file nothing happens , and there is no documentation for usage !!

Comment: Oh yeah, the index.html is missing the 'http:' from the 2 jquery .js links. Not really sure why but it works once you fix that.

Comment: i used a pseudo code , and it works , but i assigned additional class "rotating" to the items , and instead of using rotatble using element id , i used class name , and it works for all matching classes.

Comment: Where does the code use element id?

Comment: main.js file in the js folder

Comment: Ah right, yes I already changed that to a class and assigned the class name to my elements. Works when there is one element but not multiple ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes actually you can if you assing additional class to each item you want to rotate , then select them all , and assign rotatable to their parents.

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/sSXLD/1/

```
  elem.each(function(){ 
  $(this).parent().rotatable({
    autoHide: false
  });
    })

});
```

Comment: I have assigned the class to multiple elements, how do I make sure it is selecting them all?

Comment: $(".yourclass").parent().rotatable({ //
   autoHide: false
 })

Comment: That's exactly what I've done, but it doesn't work on any when there's multiple things with that class. Does it work for you?

Comment: it does !! but you have to replace id with class , i mean i used a dummy class , but ofcourse elements didn't have same id !

Comment: See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanjaypoyzer/sSXLD/), this is exactly what I've done :/

Comment: aha got your problem , check answer update , and the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/sSXLD/1/